# How to print WPF Grid paged?

Tags: wpf, printing, grid, paging

I'm printing a WPF grid. As long as the data fits on one page, everything works fine. But sometimes the grid contains more data. Therefore I need to split the grid into multiple pages. Can anybody help me?

My code looks like this (visual is the grid).

```
var printCapabilities = printDialog.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDialog.PrintTicket);

var size = new Size(printCapabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth,
     printCapabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);

visual.Measure(size);
visual.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(printCapabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth,
    printCapabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight), size));

printDialog.PrintVisual(visual, "Print ListView");
```

Should I try another control? I've tried WPF Toolkit DataGrid, but I couldn't manage to get it printed. I've heard something of a flow document, can this help me?

Best Regards
Oliver Hanappi

Comment: Hi! I'm using a FlowDocument now, which of course supports paging. Unfortunately, splitting columns on many pages is still a problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420162/how-to-print-a-wpf-flow-document-table-across-multiple-pages-if-there-are-too-man

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use PrintDocument instead of PrintVisual.  You will probably need to implement your own DocumentPaginator class to split your grid into separate printable documents, though.