# How to print a WPF flow document table across multiple pages if there are too many columns to fit on one page?

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

I think the question title is self-explaining. I have a flow document with a table which has too many columns to fit on one page. Is there a way to print the columns across multiple pages?

```
c1 = Column 1
c2 = Column 2
etc.

+-------------+ +-------------+
| Page 1      | | Page 2      |
|             | |             |
| c1 c2 c3 c4 | | c5 c6 c7 c8 |
|             | |             |
|             | |             |
|             | |             |
|             | |             |
|             | |             |
+-------------+ +-------------+
```

Best Regards
Oliver Hanappi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not possible in WPF currently. FlowDocument (and it's contents) will only ever paginate vertically, not horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible to do this.

you can calculate values using the following.

```
FlowDocument.PageWidth
FlowDocument.ColumnWidth
FlowDocument.ColumnGap
FlowDocument.PagePadding
```

This along with column width specifications in your xaml could get you the desired effect